# URL Schemes item 0 is already used

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to add Facebook SDK 3.2 to my app and one of their requirements is to ad the app ud to the location you see in the picture. My problem is that the app I want to update is already using item 0 with the name of my app to connect back to the app from Safari. I'm not the one that implemented that so I have no idea how it works. How can I keep the things the way they are and still coexist with facebook sdk?

[image]

Comment: Adde the fabebook URL as a second time (aka item 1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it as Item 1, the order won't matter, as long as you have the fbID somewhere in that URLSchemes Array.